# How to do an IN operator in peewee

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I have a database where I have users stored. Those users have a 'phone_number' property.

I want to retrieve a list of users whose 'phone_number' is contained in a list I have.

Something like:

```
contacts = ["123","321","456","654"]
friends = []
for user in User.select(User.phone_number).where(User.phone_number in contacts):
    friends.append(user.phone_number)
```

**Issue:** That piece of code returns every user's phone number and not just the ones contained in contacts.

I can achieve what I want with:

```
friends = [u.phone_number for u in User.select(User.phone_number) if u.phone_number in contacts]
```

but as far as I understand this approach is probably retrieving all users from the database first, turning them into python objects and then doing the filtering. It seems incredibly inefficient if I have a large number of users since it's python doing the filtering and not the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This documentation shows the query operators for peewee:
http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators

To answer your question specifically you can do

```
User.phone_number << contacts
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!

Comment: Python coerces the return value of `__contains__` to a boolean, so that's why we have the "<<" lshift hack.